# Alternatives to nested Select in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Working on a clustering project, I stumbled upon this, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a better solution than the one I've come up with.

**PROBLEM** : Given a `List<Point> Points` of points in R^n ( you can think at every Point as a double array fo dimension n), a `double minDistance` and a distance `Func<Point,Point,double> dist` , write a LINQ expression that returns, for each point, the set of other points in the list that are closer to him than minDistance according to dist.

My solution is the following:

```
        var lst = Points.Select( 
                x => Points.Where(z => dist(x, z) < minDistance)
                    .ToList() )
                .ToList();
```

So, after noticing that

- Using LINQ is probably not the best idea, because you get to calculate every distance twice
- The problem doesn't have much practical use
- My code, even if bad looking, works

I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to translate my code in query expression? and if so, how?
2. Is there a better way to solve this in dot notation?

Comment: `The compiler doesn't seem to like the double "from x in Points".` Why? What did you try? What error?

Comment: What benefit do you believe `Points.Select(y => y)` has over `Points` in your inner query?

Comment: @Jon Skeet : you are perfectly right, that ineer select is not needed at all. Now i feel dumb :)

Comment: @SLaks: after writing the two from x in points, and the where clause on the second one, i can't figure out how to return the proper list ... the compiler bit was juts an oversight of mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem definition, that you want "for each point, the set of other points" makes it impossible to solve without the inner query - you could just disguise it in clever manner. If you could change your data storage policy, and don't stick to LINQ then, in general, there are many approaches to [Nearest Neighbour Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) problem. You could for example hold the points sorted according to their values on one axis, which can speed-up the queries for neighbours by eliminating early some candidates without full distance calculation. Here is the paper with this approach: [Flexible Metric Nearest Neighbor Classification](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.2959).

Answer (score 0):

Because `Points` is a `List` you can take advantage of the fact that you can access each item by its index. So you can avoid comparing each item twice with something like this:

```
var lst = 
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Points.Length)
    from j in Enumerable.Range(i + 1, Points.Length - i - 1)
    where dist(Points[i], Points[j]) < minDistance
    select new 
    {
        x = Points[i], y = Points[j]
    };
```

This will return a set composed of all points within `minDistance` of each other, but not exactly what the result you wanted. If you want to turn it into some kind of `Lookup` so you can see which points are close to a given point you can do this:

```
var lst = 
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Points.Length)
     from j in Enumerable.Range(i + 1, Points.Length - i - 1)
     where dist(Points[i], Points[j]) < minDistance
     select new { x = Points[i], y = Points[j] })
    .SelectMany(pair => new[] { pair, { x = pair.y, y = pair.x })
    .ToLookup(pair => pair.x, pair => pair.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add some bool `Property` to your `Point` class to mark it's has been browsed to prevent twice calling to `dist`, something like this:

```
public class Point {
   //....
   public bool IsBrowsed {get;set;}
}
var lst = Points.Select( 
                 x => {
                       var list = Points.Where(z =>!z.IsBrowsed&&dist(x, z) < minDistance).ToList();
                       x.IsBrowsed = true;
                       return list;
                      })
                 .ToList();
```